# TextView in Nested LinearLayout is now shown

Tags: xml, android-layout

After running below code, `TextView3` is not shown. When I run the code with orientation of `LinearLayout2` as `vertical`, both `TextView2` and `TextView3` are shown. In `horizontal` orientation, only `TextView3` is shown.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/String1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/String2"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/String3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have set the `android:layout_width` for `LinearLayout2`, `TextView2` and `TextView3` to  `match_parent`.

Now when you set the orientation of `LinearLayout2` to `horizontal`, you will see `TextView3` only.

One solution is to equally distribute the width among the two `TextView`s as follows.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/String2"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/String3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

TextView 2's width is `match_parent`, meaning it will fill the width of the parent container.

When the parent linear layout is vertical, this doesn't matter, because there is only one thing on that "row", text view 2.

When it's horizontal, TextView2 fills the width, then TextView3 is placed after this, but it's off-screen.

If you'd like TextView2 and 3 to be next to each other, you can use `layout_weight` for the second LinearLayout.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="@string/String1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="@string/String2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```